# Ambiguous column in INNER JOIN statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting confused with this. I have searched the internet and it is still confusing me. I have the following tables:

Meetings: `meeting_id`, `title`, `chairman`, `secretary`, `occurances`
Rooms: `room_id`, `room`, `date`, `time`, `meeting_id`

I want everything to be displayed on a table. My PHP is as follows:

```
    <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Meetings INNER JOIN Rooms ON meeting_id = Rooms.meeting_id")
or die(mysql_error()); ;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo 'There Arent Any Meetings Setup Yet';
    } else {

echo "<table border='0'><table border width=100%><tr><th>Title</th><th>Chairperson</th><th>Secretary</th><th>Terms of Reference</th><th>Occurances</th><th>Room</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th>";        

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><br/>" . $info['title']." </td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" . $info['chairperson']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" . $info['secretary']."</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" . $info['tof']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" . $info['occurances']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" . $info['room']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" . $info['date']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" . $info['time']. "</td>";

        }
    }
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";


?>
```

It comes out with the following error message:

> Column 'meeting_id' in on clause is ambiguous

I am trying to display all the fields from the meetings table and obviously the room, date and time only.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define which table you want `meeting_id` to be selected from.

e.g.

```
`SELECT * FROM Meetings INNER JOIN Rooms ON Meetings.meeting_id = Rooms.meeting_id`
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix *both* columns in the join with their table names, i.e.

```
FROM Meetings INNER JOIN Rooms ON Meetings.meeting_id = Rooms.meeting_id
```

The error message explains the problem quite clearly, actually: whenever you specify a column whose name exists in multiple tables, you must be explicit about which table's column you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states the meeting_id is ambiguous so you need to specify which table you want to constraint as meeting_id.

```
SELECT * FROM Meetings INNER JOIN Rooms ON Meetings.meeting_id = Rooms.meeting_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Meetings INNER JOIN Rooms ON Meetings.meeting_id = Rooms.meeting_id")
```

When column names are same on `join` columns, you must explicitly mention those columns belonging to a specific table.