# Order By meeting_id DESC

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ambiguous column in INNER JOIN statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719465/ambiguous-column-in-inner-join-statement)

i have a table where a list of meetings are gathered from two tables by using the inner join sql statement. I am now having a problem by ordering it in descending order with the meeting_id primary (in the meetings table) & foreign key (in the rooms table).

```
    <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Meetings INNER JOIN Rooms ON Meetings.meeting_id = Rooms.meeting_id ORDER BY meeting_id")
or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo '<h2>There Arent Any Meetings Setup Yet</h2>';
    } else {

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Title: '. $info['title']." </td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Chairman: '. $info['chairperson']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Secretary: '. $info['secretary']."</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Terms Of Reference: '. $info['tof']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Occurances: '. $info['occurances']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Room: '. $info['room']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Date: '. $info['date']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Time: '. $info['time']. "</td>";
        echo "<hr>";
        }
    }
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";


?>
```

I am getting the following error message:

'Column 'meeting_id' in order clause is ambiguous'

my tables look like this:

Meetings: meeting_id, title, chairman, secretary, occurances

Rooms: room_id, room, date, time, meeting_id

Comment: Why did you ask the same question at least twice though the reason why it displays such error was already given to you.? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719465/ambiguous-column-in-inner-join-statement/8719501#8719501 Are you trying to be funny here?

Comment: NO!!!!!!!! im not trying to be funny! This is another problem but similar also to my previous one! and everytime I get another problem and ask in the same thread, noone seems to anwser! Anyway what is your problem if I was to ask another but similar question?

Comment: @user1114080: The exact same error, but in a different part of the query, and you can't figure it out?  Please, understand StackOverflow isn't your debugging service.  You should at least *try* to fix errors before asking questions.  Asking many incremental questions in order to fix small, easy to figure out bugs could be considered abusive of the community.

Answer (score 2):

As the message states, it's ambiguous; both `Rooms` and `Messages` have a `meeting_id`, and SQL doesn't know that you've joined them. Just specify one or the other:

```
$result =
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Meetings
                 INNER JOIN Rooms ON Meetings.meeting_id = Rooms.meeting_id
                 ORDER BY Rooms.meeting_id")
```

Comment: you'd probably find it helpful to not have a `meeting_id` column in the `meetings` table.  It should just be `id`

Comment: i have several other tables in my database which uses the meeting_id as a foreign key.